# Test of confidence intervals?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In one of my assignments I have to "test" if the confidence intervals for a set of parameters in a mixed effect model is accurate. I'm asked to simulate from fittet parameters and there after refit them using the same model many times, and lastly take 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of them and compare with the original CIs. My question is, how does this procedure in anyway measure how accurate my original confidence intervals are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you simulate data from fitted parameters you find another estimate of the parameter. If the original 95% CI is valid, about
95% of these new estimates ought to lie in the original CI.

You must be studying, or about to study, parametric bootstrapping. There are
so many different formulations of this idea that I hesitate to get
into a theoretical discussion, without knowing the particulars of your course and text, for fear of causing additional confusion.

Take a very simple case. I have a sample of $n = 36$ observations
from $Norm(\mu, \sigma=10).$ Suppose $\bar X = 105.9,$ so that
a 95% z-interval for $\mu$ is $106.9 \pm 1.96(10/6)$ or $(103.6, 110.2)$

Now I take a large number, say $B = 100000,$ of samples of size 36
from $Norm(106.9, 10)$ and use R to carry out the procedure you 
describe.

```
 B = 10^5; mu.est = 106.9; sg = 10; n = 36
 RDTA = matrix(rnorm(B*n, mu.est, sg),nrow=B)
 x.bar = rowMeans(RDTA)  # each row of B x n matrix is a sample
 quantile(x.bar, c(.025, .975))
 ##      2.5%    97.5% 
 ##  103.6111 110.1773
```

The result is not far from the original CI $(103.6, 110,2).$
In this trivial case, the agreement is not surprising because
we are just re-establishing by simulation that $\bar X \sim Norm(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$

In more complex cases, modifications must be made in the procedure, especially when dealing with distributions
and estimators that have heavily skewed distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still curious in the case where the new CI isn't inside the old CI for some of the parameters(the variance parameters in specific), what can we infer from this? I've also made histograms over the 1000 sets of parameters I've generated and the ones that have CI not inside the new CI also seem to not follow a normal distribution. What is the connection here? what can we infer in a scenario like this?

Comment: Difficult to be specific w/o more info:  Possibilities: (1) Nr. of iterations B too small, (2) The 'naive' bootstrap I gather you're using and that I used in return is only for symmetrical dist'ns. Asym. distn's need bias adj quantile method.  Dist'n of variance or SD is often skewed. (3) Sometimes best to bootstrap a ratio to get bootstrap CI for scale parameter. These are only hints and bits. Each of above would take a page to address properly. If you have a specific case, suggest you start new question w/ details. Might get coherent response. But lots of bogus bootstrap 'experts' around.